# How to check if string is valid date?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am getting a string value from user and I want to check if the string is valid date or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in XPages SSJS context:

```
var df = new java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance();
df.setLenient(false);
try {
    var d  = df.parse(dateString);
    return true;
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
```

This code returns true if dateString is a valid date string and false if not.

`setLenient(false)` is used to make a strong validation.

Answer (score 0):

try this function:

```
    function ifDate(date) {
        return !isNaN(Date.parse(date));
    }
```